Slow log in Redis Cache
I would like to run slow log 10 command in Redis cache to check which is taking so long time and I would like to know if it is possible to run the slow log 10 in azure portal or do we need to have third party app. And where we run in azure (Azure Cache for Redis) .
Error :
Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=1720KiB, 6016ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=SETEX, next: SETEX data:list:8756789:020250107_09_30_00:S00, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 86, last-in: 11688, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 121831, serverEndpoint: xxxxx, conn-sec: 74643,13, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxxxxx(Redis-v2.8.0.27420), IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=16,Free=32751,Min=4,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=34,QueuedItems=4,CompletedItems=7022584,Timers=156), v: 2.8.0.27420

Timeout awaiting response (outbound=3588KiB, inbound=499KiB, 5438ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=EXISTS, next: GET data:list:2345876:020241220_14_00_00:S00, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 54330, last-in: 1880304, cur-in: 1793806, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 128364, serverEndpoint: xxxx, conn-sec: 76871,54, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxxxx(Redis-v2.8.0.27420), IOCP: (Busy=4,Free=996,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=15,Free=32752,Min=4,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=59,QueuedItems=6,CompletedItems=7238691,Timers=154), v: 2.8.0.27420


Since this is stackoverflow which is coding related, and since you're clearly using SE.Redis: SE.Redis makes this available on the IServer API, for example: multiplexer.GetServers().First().SlowlogGet() - note that if this is a cluster, you'll need to check either all servers, or the server for the relevant keys

As for how to do this in the azure portal: see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure?tabs=access-keys#redis-console
